# How to find the real datatype of a variable in R?

Tags: r, matrix, types, pca

Datatypes in R have always confused me, and I'm sorry if this is an elementary question.  I know that the `$loadings` attribute in R is supposed to be a matrix.  even the documentation says that if you type `?loadings`:  it says it is `the matrix of variable loadings`.

```
arrests_pca <- princomp(USArrests, cor=TRUE)
typeof(arrests_pca$loadings)
```

....returns

```
[1] "double"
```

...and so I tried to find the class:

```
> class(arrests_pca$loadings)
[1] "loadings"
```

Comment: `is.matrix(arrests_pca$loadings)`.  You could also remove the loadings class with `unclass()`, and it becomes the "true" matrix.  It's the print method that puts it in a different class, but it's really a matrix under the hood.

Comment: So, you'd have to know that it was a matrix to even try that, right?

Comment: No.  It will tell you TRUE or FALSE.  But you can see that it's probably a matrix or a data frame by looking at it in the console.  Also, you can always use the default print method to see its underlying structure.  `print.default(arrests_pca$loadings)`

Comment: @Candic3 ... which isn't too difficult if you read the documentation ...

Comment: `str(arrests_pca$loadings)` shows you that it's a two-dimensional numeric, though it doesn't explicitly say "matrix".

Answer (score 2):

Use `str(arrests_pca$loadings)`. It returns

```
 loadings [1:4, 1:4] -0.536 -0.583 -0.278 -0.543 0.418 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Murder" "Assault" "UrbanPop" "Rape"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Comp.1" "Comp.2" "Comp.3" "Comp.4"
```

You can see on the first line that it's a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Only if you know what `[1:4, 1:4]` means

Comment: perhaps edit your last line to say something like "The first line shows that the structure is a 4x4 matrix" - i.e. don't imply that the OP should already have known this / that it should be obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mode()`

```
mode(arrests_pca$loadings)
```